# How to filter an array of object?

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array of objects (show below) and I would like to write a function that returns the same array but with the "object(s)" that meet the criterion removed.

The function would :

1- check if the index exists
2- if it exists, checks for the required value and if the object's index is equal to that value, remove the whole object.

For example :

```
    Array
(
    [course] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Programmation Web
                    [description] => 
                    [public] => 0
                    [requests] => 0
                    [id] => 245
                    [members] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 11
                                    [name] => Robert Smith
                                )

                        )

                    [projects] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 1923
                                    [title] => Sans titre (1)
                                    [type] => portfolio
                                )

                            )

                    [project_count] => 1
                    [admins] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [member] => 11
                                    [firstname] => Robert
                                    [lastname] => Smith
                                )

                        )

                    [topic_name] => Le PHP
                    [activites] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [topic_name] => 
                                    [topic_id] => 42
                                    [post_parent] => 107
                                    [post_body] => Oui moi aussi je me demande ça.
                                    [post_id] => 109
                                )

                        )

                    [forums] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [forum_name] => Discussion générale
                                    [forum_id] => 101
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Les bases de données
                    [description] => 
                    [public] => 0
                    [jointype] => controlled
                    [grouptype] => course
                    [membershiptype] => admin
                    [topic_name] => Difficulté
                    [activites] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [topic_name] => 
                                    [topic_id] => 44
                                    [post_parent] => 111
                                    [post_body] => Ouah!
                                    [post_id] => 112
                                )

                        )

                    [forums] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [forum_name] => Le MySQL
                                    [forum_id] => 103
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

If there's an object whose **admins->member** value is equal to 11, remove the object and return the array without this object.  The returned array would thus be :

```
        Array
(
    [course] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Programmation Web
                    [description] => 
                    [public] => 0
                    [requests] => 0
                    [id] => 245
                    [members] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 11
                                    [name] => Robert Smith (smithrobert)
                                )

                        )

                    [projects] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 1923
                                    [title] => Sans titre (1)
                                    [type] => portfolio
                                )

                            )

                    [project_count] => 1
                    [admins] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [member] => 11
                                    [firstname] => Robert
                                    [lastname] => Smith
                                )

                        )

                    [topic_name] => Le PHP
                    [activites] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [topic_name] => 
                                    [topic_id] => 42
                                    [post_parent] => 107
                                    [post_body] => Oui moi aussi je me demande ça.
                                    [post_id] => 109
                                )

                        )

                    [forums] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [forum_name] => Discussion générale
                                    [forum_id] => 101
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Have look at [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter).

Comment: Duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814872/how-to-filter-out-an-object-from-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Want to filter an array? Use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter)!

```
$new_array = array_filter($array, function($obj){
    if (isset($obj->admins)) {
        foreach ($obj->admins as $admin) {
            if ($admin->member == 11) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Hi !  Thanks for your neat answer!  It looks like it's supposed to work but it's not working ... $new_array is just the same as $array after I passed it through your callback function.

Comment: Very strange indeed, it worked for me. And by looking at your data structure, I can't see why it wouldn't... :S

Comment: The array starts with an index "course", would that be why it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `array_filter` with a custom callback:

```
function filter_callback($element) {
  if (isset($element->foo) && $element->foo == 'some_value') {
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}

$arr = array_filter($arr, 'filter_callback');
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide another approach with using case :
function used [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-key-exists.php) & [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.in-array.php)

```
$params = [
    "nom" => 'titof',
    "prenom" => 'edoe',
    "age" => '25'
    ];

$data = [
    0 => [
        'nom' => 'john',
        'prenom' => 'doe',
        'age' => '25'
        ],
    1 => [
        'nom' => 'lola',
        'prenom' => 'la grandi',
        'age' => '72'
        ],
    2 => [
        'nom' => 'michael',
        'prenom' => 'Pamal',
        'age' => '25'
        ]
    ];

function getFilteredArray($params, $data) {
   $filtredArray = [];
   foreach($params as $key => $value) {
       foreach($data as $index => $item) {
           if(array_key_exists($key, $item) && in_array($value, $params)) {
               if($item[$key] == $value ){
                   $filtredArray[$index] = $item;
               } else {
                   continue;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   return $filtredArray;
}
```

You can found it here :
https://gist.github.com/ADCPD/a00df3f44b96322fbd6818f216e9d982

Answer (score 0):

Provide another method:

```
public function getArrayFiltered($aFilterKey, $aFilterValue, $array) {
    $filtered_array = array();
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (isset($value->$aFilterKey)) {
            if ($value->$aFilterKey == $aFilterValue) {
                $filtered_array[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $filtered_array;
}
```