# Returning an array within multiple objects and arrays

Tags: php, arrays, object

I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax to print:

```
[Agriculture] => AGR 
[Animals] => AN 
[Arts and Humanities] => ART
```

within the $TOPIC object.

What makes this a bit more confusing is that $TOPIC is in an object that can be called in a different order than this example. So instead of [3] => stdClass Object, it could be [4] => stdClass Object, (or any number).

Some sample foreach syntax is included below; it doesn't work though.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [123456] => stdClass Object
        (
            [required_actions] => Array
                (
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [maxlength] =>
                            [value] => $MESSAGE
                            [options_hash] =>
                        )
                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [maxlength] =>
                            [value] => $NAME_PREFIX
                            [options_hash] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Ms.] => Ms.
                                    [Mrs.] => Mrs.
                                    [Mr.] => Mr.
                                )
                        )
                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [maxlength] =>
                            [value] => $TOPIC
                            [options_hash] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Agriculture] => AGR
                                    [Animals] => AN
                                    [Arts and Humanities] => ART
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)

foreach ($json->123456->required_actions as $info) {
       echo $info->value => $TOPIC->options_hash;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to search for the parent object by value, and then request the child object's array. Here is what I used:

```
foreach ($json->123456->required_actions as $info) {
        if ('$TOPIC' == $info->value) {
       print_r($info->options_hash);
 }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826358/how-to-filter-an-array-of-object would be another and probably faster way to do this