# Deleting JSON data using PHP and POST requests

Tags: php, json

I would like some PHP code that deletes things from a JSON file using PHP, exemplifying:

**let's say I have this JSON file:**

```
{
     "aaa": [
         {
             "title": "xx",
             "description": "6",
         },
         {
             "title": "tt",
             "description": "b",
         }
     ]
}
```

So I want it to get the string via POST and then delete the whole part of the JSON which has the string given via POST.

For example, let's say that I send "xx" via POST request, after the PHP script runs, I want the JSON to look like this, without the one that was deleted:

```
{
     "aaa": [
         {
             "title": "tt",
             "description": "b",
         }
     ]
}
```

I tried in every way I found by searching the internet, but I could not do anything that did it correctly. Thanks in advance!

***I KNOW THAT THERE'S A LOT OF QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS LIKE THIS, BUT NONE OF THEM WAS USEFUL FOR ME, SO I AM ASKING BY MYSELF, DON'T NEED NOBODY TO MARK THIS AS DUPLICATE, IF YOU KNOW HOW TO DO THIS, ANSWER HERE, ELSE...***

Comment: Could you please link to those other questions / answers and explain how they didn't help? It'll save time in the future. Also please show what you have tried

Comment: You're really just looking to filter the array by the `title` property of each object. This should help and if it doesn't, please explain how ~ [How to filter an array of object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826358/how-to-filter-an-array-of-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is...

1. Parse the JSON file into a PHP data structure using `file_get_contents()` and `json_decode()`
2. Filter the `aaa` array by title, removing the entries that match your POST data using `array_filter()`
3. Write the modified data structure back to the file as a JSON string using `json_encode()` and `file_put_contents()`

Here's an example

```php
$file = 'path/to/file.json';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file));
$title = trim($_POST['title']); // assuming this is all checked / validated / etc
$data->aaa = array_values(array_filter($data->aaa, function($item) use ($title) {
    return (bool) strcmp($item->title, $title); // returns 0 if strings match
}));
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($data));
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/60MoG

Comment: @luclzzBR2252 I've just added `array_values` in to re-index the filtered array. Otherwise you end up with an object with numeric keys

Comment: That's what I wanted to do, but I didn't know how to explain

Answer (score 0):

I realize you have an accepted answer, but with such a simple json object, you can simply create a new object and add the aaa array with elements that don't match the one you want to delete.

```
<?php

$file = '/path/to/your/file';

// Delete this one
$_POST['delete'] = 'xx';

// Get file contents and decode it
$str = file_get_contents( $file );
$json = json_decode( $str );

// Create a new object
$temp = new stdClass;

// Add only the objects we want to keep
foreach( $json->aaa as $obj )
    if( $obj->title != $_POST['delete'] )
        $temp->aaa[] = $obj;

// Replace the file contents
file_put_contents( 
    $file, 
    json_encode( $temp ) 
);
```